# 1a 1b 1c level descriptors in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How construct a dynamic MySQL Query where the value of `MAX(InvoiceNo)` should be

```
1a,1b,1c...1z,2a,2b...2z,3a...
```

The query is

```
$max = "SELECT MAX( InvoiceNo ) as InvoiceNomulti FROM invoice_balance";
```

[Here is my fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22cf6/1)

Comment: This question is very vague. What do you mean by "1a,1b,1c"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select InvoiceNo  from invoice_balance order by InvoiceNo  asc limit 3
```

This query will return you the 1a,1b,1c

Comment: Please read the question correctly, What he needs is to make the MAX( InvoiceNo ) as 1a,1b,1c...1z,2a,2b...2z,3a...

Comment: Plz share the structure of tables, and plz explain the requirements little more.